# ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found. when trying to install get-pip.py

Tags: python, pip

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\seant\Downloads\ez_setup.py", line 30, in <module>
    from urllib2 import urlopen
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 94, in <module>
    import httplib
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 72, in <module>
    import socket
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 47, in <module>
    import _socket
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

That's the error i get, i downloaded depends32 and it shows me a bunch of APIS with quesiton marks. I'm on windows10, could that possibly be an issue?

Is there an easy work around for this?

Comment: Hi, have you found a solution since then?